# Get all fields in lookup object

Tags: fields, describefieldresult

I have a custom object called `Job` and Job has a couple of Lookup fields linking with `Group`, `Account`, `Contact`, `Custom Object`. If I iterate through each object I get:

> Too many fields describes: 101

What's the best way to get `Job` object structure (including all fields and fields belong to those Lookup objects)?

Comment: Are you doing this in Apex? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Update your metadata version. The describe limits have been completely lifted afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Describe Limits have been removed since [Summer '14](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer14/New+Apex+Enhancements). So you just need `apiVersion >= 28.0` in your `-meta.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>28.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code you could try to execute the following using the REST API.

Object describe: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_describe.htm

Then you can filter the content and do a field describe: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_describe.htm

As the documentation suggests: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm#apex_describe_object_all_fields

> You can only have 100fields member variable statements in an Apex class or trigger.